# Get Laravel Eloquent query with bindings in place

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

When I `dd(\DB::getQueryLog())` I get something like the following:

```
array (size=3)
      'query' => string 'select * from `clicks` where `clicks`.`user_id` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) and `created_at` between ? and ?' (length=114)
      'bindings' => 
        array (size=12)
          0 => int 70
          1 => int 69
          2 => int 68
          3 => int 67
          4 => int 66
          5 => int 65
          6 => int 64
          7 => int 63
          8 => int 60
          9 => int 58
          10 => 
            object(Carbon\Carbon)[681]
              public 'date' => string '2014-12-27 20:06:39.000000' (length=26)
              public 'timezone_type' => int 3
              public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
          11 => 
            object(Carbon\Carbon)[684]
              public 'date' => string '2015-01-26 20:06:39.000000' (length=26)
              public 'timezone_type' => int 3
              public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
      'time' => float 932.67
```

How do I get the query with all of the bindings all in place so I can just copy it to MySQL Workbench and tinker with it without having to add those bindings manually each time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The actual SQL string is never available on the PHP side of things. You can try to manually work things out and replace the `?` with the bindings though:

```
echo vsprintf(str_replace('?', '%s', $queryString), $bindings);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I made a function in my controller to do this:

```
public function create(Request $request){ //you are in some function of your controller
    DB::enableQueryLog(); //enable query log
      SomeModel::create($request->all()); //your query running
    $queryLog = DB::getQueryLog(); //get query log
    $this->showExecutedQueries($queryLog); //calling my function
}
```

> My function:

```
public function showExecutedQueries($queryLog){
        foreach ($queryLog as $query){
            $aQuery[] = vsprintf(str_replace('?', '%s',$query['query']),$query['bindings']);
        }
        echo '<pre>'; print_r($aQuery); die();
    }
```

It's going to display all the executed queries in order inside an array;

Comment: hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Note that there is already an accepted answer to this question. Please [edit] your answer if needed to ensure that it improves upon other answers already present in this question.